# Converting a string to dummy encoded variables

Tags: categorical-data

Here's the data

```
PlayerID, Characters, Win or Lose
```

I can make it look like this

```
8PYPY0LLQ,valkyrie5 ,  chr_witch4 ,  hog_rider5 ,  zapMachine1 ,  mega_minion3 ,  baby_dragon2 ,  bomber7 ,  skeleton_horde1, 0
```

Or like this

```
2GRG822L9,"barbarians8, valkyrie5, chr_balloon3, fire_spirits8, minion8, firespirit_hut6, rage4, skeleton_horde3,",1
```

The second column is an 8 character combination from 70+ n characters.

I need to encode the variables to be dummy variables, so each character gets its own column. Is there a way to do this in python/R? I'm assuming you have to leave the second column as a string rather than outputting a csv file that looks like this.

```
2GRG822L9,barbarians8, valkyrie5, chr_balloon3, fire_spirits8, minion8, firespirit_hut6, rage4, skeleton_horde3,1
8PYPY0LLQ,valkyrie5 ,  chr_witch4 ,  hog_rider5 ,  zapMachine1 ,  mega_minion3 ,  baby_dragon2 ,  bomber7 ,  skeleton_horde1,0
```

It should probably look like this before dummy encoding (I can get rid of commas within the string)

```
2GRG822L9,"barbarians8, valkyrie5, chr_balloon3, fire_spirits8, minion8, firespirit_hut6, rage4, skeleton_horde3,",1
8PYPY0LLQ,"valkyrie5 ,  chr_witch4 ,  hog_rider5 ,  zapMachine1 ,  mega_minion3 ,  baby_dragon2 ,  bomber7 ,  skeleton_horde1,",0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple with python:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
data = [('2GRG822L9',"barbarians8,valkyrie5,chr_balloon3,fire_spirits8,minion8,firespirit_hut6,rage4,skeleton_horde3",1), ('8PYPY0LLQ',"valkyrie5,chr_witch4,hog_rider5,zapMachine1,mega_minion3,baby_dragon2,bomber7,skeleton_horde1",0)]
df = DataFrame.from_records(data,columns=('PlayerID', 'Characters', 'Result'))
df = df.drop('Characters', 1).join(df.Characters.str.get_dummies(','))
```

The result:

```
    PlayerID  Result  baby_dragon2  barbarians8  bomber7  chr_balloon3  \
0  2GRG822L9       1             0            1        0             1   
1  8PYPY0LLQ       0             1            0        1             0   

   chr_witch4  fire_spirits8  firespirit_hut6  hog_rider5  mega_minion3  \
0           0              1                1           0             0   
1           1              0                0           1             1   

   minion8  rage4  skeleton_horde1  skeleton_horde3  valkyrie5  zapMachine1  
0        1      1                0                1          1            0  
1        0      0                1                0          1            1
```

Comment: You are welcome (and also to the site). If it solved the problem, please accept the answer so we can improve our stats.

Comment: Hey @Emre, I know this ancillary question is off-topic from the question above, but how do I find the best card now? Is it feature importance, feature selection (same thing?), a clustering problem, or something else? Trying to find the next tutorial to guide me in learning data science. Thank you!

Comment: If by best card you mean _most predictive of the result_, look at the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information), for example with [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif)